# justify-content: flex-end makes scrollbar disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have this html having flex div box contains flex items and i want to make them generate from the bottom

so as you see when you open it will have `inner` at the bottom then when you press `add` it will start going to the top

but the scrollbar will never appear but for it to appear i have to remove `justify-content: flex-end;`

but then the content will start from top and the only way to keep it at bottom is to use a script to always scroll to the bottom on add and I want to do it with pure CSS if possible while it being Flex

with `justify-content: flex-end;`

```js
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {
  let inner = document.createElement('div');
  inner.innerText = 'Inner'
  document.getElementById('inner').appendChild(inner);
}
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child-2 {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 4px 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">
  Top
  <button id="add">Add Inner</button>
  </div>
  <div id="inner" class="child-2">
     <div>Inner</div>
     <div>Inner</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

without `justify-content: flex-end;`

```js
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {
  let inner = document.createElement('div');
  inner.innerText = 'Inner'
  document.getElementById('inner').appendChild(inner);
}
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child-2 {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 4px 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">
  Top
  <button id="add">Add Inner</button>
  </div>
  <div id="inner" class="child-2">
     <div>Inner</div>
     <div>Inner</div>
  </div>
</div>
```